# Postgresql why 'm' like E'%\\m%' is true

Tags: postgresql

First lets assume we have this strings with escapes:

```
select E'%m%' as m, E'%\m%' as m1, E'%\\m%' as m2, E'%\\\m%' as m3, E'%\\\\m%' m4;
  m  | m1  |  m2  |  m3  |  m4   
-----+-----+------+------+-------
 %m% | %m% | %\m% | %\m% | %\\m%
```

Now we will try to matsh this with like:

```
select 'm' like E'%m%' as m, 'm' like E'%\m%' as m1, 'm' like E'%\\m%' as m2, 'm' like E'%\\\m%' as m3,  'm' like E'%\\\\m%' m4;
 m to m | m to m1  | m to m2 | m to m3 | m to m4 
--------+----------+---------+---------+--------
 t      | t        | t       | t       | f
```

I can understand why m to m is true and m to m1 is true.

What i can`t understand is why m to m2 (and m to m3 also) true.

Can anybody describe why this it or pass me psql doc section with description of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because [`LIKE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-LIKE) uses escaping too, like [C-style escapes](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-STRINGS-ESCAPE).

```
E'%\\\m%'  = '%\m%'
E'%\\\\m%' = '%\\m%'
```

thus

```
'm' LIKE '%\m%'  = 'm' LIKE '%\m%'  ESCAPE '\' = 'm' LIKE '%m%'  ESCAPE ''
'm' LIKE '%\\m%' = 'm' LIKE '%\\m%' ESCAPE '\' = 'm' LIKE '%\m%' ESCAPE ''
```

but

```
'\m' LIKE '%\\m%' = TRUE
```

Note: that's because you use unknown escape sequences (`\m`) in both your constants & like-expressions. You should not rely on these, use proper escaping everywhere.

**Edit**: my examples use [`standard_conforming_strings`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/runtime-config-compatible.html#GUC-STANDARD-CONFORMING-STRINGS) = on (which is on by default after 9.1)

Comment: In this case it seems that using `standard_conforming_strings`, i.e. not using `E'...'` strings, would greatly simplify things.

Comment: Ah, yes. Forget to mention that.